# Get Numeric Value from DataGridViewCell?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to retrieve numeric values from a `DataGridView`. So far, the only way I've found is to retrieve them as a string and convert them to numeric.

```
Convert.ToDouble(MyGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

There must be an easier way. The cell is originally populated from a `DataSet` with a numeric field value but since the `DataGridViewCell` object returns it as an object, I can't do a straight assignment. I must be missing something simple here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I've actually just recently dealt with this problem and `TryParse` I think is your best bet with respect to robustness, but don't forget to check if the value in the Cell is `null`, if so `TryParse` will fail and throw up an error.

```
double d = 0;
if(grid[col,row].Value != null)
  double.TryParse(grid[col,row].Value.ToString(), out d);
```

I would also recommend avoiding a straight cast, unless you know absolutely what type you are converting and that there will, in fact, be a value there, it will probably at some point cause an error in your code.

Answer (score 2):

With `DataGridViewCell` you can just cast the `.Value` to your known type; the following is a complete example that shows this happening (using double) from a `DataTable` (like your example).
Additionally, `Convert.To{blah}(...)` and `Convert.ChangeType(...)` might be helpful.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        DataTable table = new DataTable
        {
            Columns = {
                {"Foo", typeof(double)},
                {"Bar", typeof(string)}
            },
            Rows = {
                {123.45, "abc"},
                {678.90, "def"}
            }
        };
        Form form = new Form();
        DataGridView grid = new DataGridView {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill, DataSource = table};
        form.Controls.Add(grid);
        grid.CurrentCellChanged += delegate
        {
            form.Text = string.Format("{0}: {1}",
                grid.CurrentCell.Value.GetType(),
                grid.CurrentCell.Value);

            if (grid.CurrentCell.Value is double)
            {
                double val = (double)grid.CurrentCell.Value;
                form.Text += " is a double: " + val;
            }
        };
        Application.Run(form);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DataGridViewCell` has `ValueType` property.  You can use to do directly cast the value to that type without first converting it to string:

```
if(MyGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].ValueType!=null &&
   MyGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].ValueType == Double)
 return (Double)MyGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
```

Comment: Since the ValueType is a Type, you can't cast *directly* to the ValueType; however, you can check the Type is something you expect, though - but "is" might do just as well (nulls not withstanding).

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting? `Convert.ToDouble` has an overloaded method that takes an object, so you shouldn't need the `ToString()`? Unless you are doing a `TryParse`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `DataGridViewCell.Value` is an Object type, you really need to convert it to the appropriate type, `Double` or any `numeric` type in your case. The `DataGridView` contents aren't strongly typed so you have to cast the values retrieved from its cells.

Comment: It is the .Value you need to cast, not the DataGridViewCell itself.

Comment: yep, am so sleepy when i typed my reply. :)