# How do I save info from an unbound datagridview to SQL database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have been trying for hours to get the info in my datagridview to save to the datatable.  The datagridview is populated from a combobox where selections are made.  What I cant figure out is how to convert the `qty_Ordered` to `int`.  I believe it will work once I have that.

Also, is it possible to use the column names of the datagridview rather than `Cells[]`?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in purchase_Order_ItemsDataGridView.Rows)
    {
        if (!row.IsNewRow)
        {
            SQL = @"INSERT INTO Purchase_Order_Items (Purchase_Order_ID, Part_Number, Qty_Ordered, Work_Order_Number)
        VALUES(@purchase_Order_Id, @part_Number, @qty_Ordered, @work_Order_Number)";

            sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, DataAccessClass.sql_Connection);

            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@purchase_Order_ID", purchase_Order_Id);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@part_Number", row.Cells[1].Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty_Ordered", row.Cells[2].Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@work_Order_Number", row.Cells[3].Value);

            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get some error? What the exact problem you're facing?

Comment: @Alejandro; yes I am getting `Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric`

Comment: When you create your `DataGridView`, you should specify the `ValueType` for each `DataGridViewColumn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?  Admittedly a stopgap solution but it does convert it to int.

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty_Ordered", int.parse(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()));
```

edit: This link might help you more -
[Get Numeric Value from DataGridViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154697/get-numeric-value-from-datagridviewcell)

It deals with ways to convert the cell with a bit more robustness than the above solution, would would fail dramatically when your value is null.

edit 2:  Looks like the above solution isn't robust enough.  The below code is more robust.

```
int qtyordered;

if (!int.TryParse(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out qtyordered)
    qtyordered = 0;

sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty_Ordered", qtyordered);
```

Loathing's answer would work the best since it'd work transparently with your current code, however it's a bit tricky.  You need to expose the datatable's column so that you can modify the type.  And you need to do that when / after the column has been created and before you begin adding data.

```
purchase_Order_ItemsDataGridView.Columns[2].ValueType = typeof(int);
```

You need to put this somewhere early on, before you begin populating the table but after you created the columns.

Comment: That is on the right track.  I now get the error `Input string was not in a correct format`.  Should I `Parse` before putting it into the command string?

Comment: If you want to parse before putting it into the command string, then I definitely recommend using TryParse instead of parse.  It'll let you know when a value can't be parsed to the specified data type.  However, your error is because of the cell value.  If you can guarantee that there're only numbers inside, then you must have an empty cell in that column somewhere (aka null value).